# Error while using resnet50 model - project image captioning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to solve this error to complete my project but I dont get to know what I should do.
Help me fixing this.

Code:

```
resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=224,224,3),pooling='avg') 
resnet = load_model('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
print("="*150) 
print("RESNET MODEL LOADED")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\drlng\Desktop\image-captioning-keras-resnet-main (2)\image-captioning-keras-resnet-main\app.py", line 62, in <module>
    resnet = load_model('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
  File "C:\Users\drlng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 206, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects,
  File "C:\Users\drlng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 181, in load_model_from_hdf5
    raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
ValueError: No model found in config file.
```

Comment: please upload your code as well.

Comment: resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3),pooling='avg')


resnet = load_model('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')

print("="*150)
print("RESNET MODEL LOADED")

Comment: In `resnet = load_model('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')`, model path has a problem

Comment: yeah ... where should i keep this pretrained model file . Now  i am having it in my project folder

Comment: It should be inside the same folder:  `filename.py` and `pretrained weight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=224,224,3),pooling='avg') 
resnet = load_model('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
print("="*150) 
print("RESNET MODEL LOADED")
```

Folder:

```
├── project
    ├── your_python_file.py
    └── resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
```

Comment: now also i am having it in the project folder only as like you have mentioned